# Error could not get function by ref in Vue script setup

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, ref

I'm doing a flip card game by Vue 3 and using `<script setup>`. And got trouble when I try handle card flipping back when choosed 2 different cards. My code aimming to flip back card use its index when choosed wrong

- File InteractScene.vue

```
<script setup>
import CardGame from "@/components/CardGame.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

const rules = ref([]);

defineProps({
    cardContext: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => []
    }
});
const checkRule = (card) => {
    let rule = rules.value;
    if (rule.length === 2) return false;
    rule.push(card);

    if (rule.length === 2 && rule[0].value === rule[1].value) {
        console.log("true...");
    } else if (rule.length === 2 && rule[0].value !== rule[1].value) {
        console.log(`card-${rule} and card-${rule[1].index}`);
        ref.value[`card-${rule[0].index}`][0].onFlipBackCard();
        ref.value[`card-${rule[1].index}`][0].onFlipBackCard();
    } else return false;
};
</script>
<template>
    <div class="scene">
        <h1>Interact Component here</h1>
        <CardGame v-for="(card, index) in cardContext"
                  :key="index"
                  :ref="`card-${index}`"
                  :img-back-face-url="`images/${card}.png`"
                  v-bind:card="{ index, value: card }"
                  :rules="rules"
                  @flip="checkRule($event)"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

- File CardGame.vue

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue";

    const emits = defineEmits(["flip"]);

    const isFlipped = ref(false);

    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/valid-define-props
    const { card, imgBackFaceUrl } = defineProps({
        card: [String, Number, Array, Object],
        imgBackFaceUrl: String
    });

    const onToggleFlipCard = () => {
        isFlipped.value = !isFlipped.value;
        if (isFlipped.value) {
            emits("flip", card);
        }
    };
    const onFlipBackCard = () => {
        isFlipped.value = false;
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-inner"
             :class="{'is-flipped': isFlipped}"
             v-on:click="onToggleFlipCard"
        >
            <div class="card-face card_face-font">
                <div class="card-content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-face card_face-back">
                <div class="card-content"
                     :style="{ backgroundImage: `url('/src/assets/${imgBackFaceUrl}')`}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I got this error on web console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZZZf.png)

In my opinionn the problem maybe the reference was not provided from provider or receiver.
In InteractScene.vue the error come from

```
...
        ref.value[`card-${rule[0].index}`][0].onFlipBackCard();
        ref.value[`card-${rule[1].index}`][0].onFlipBackCard();
...
```

And in GameCard.vue, onFlipBackCard is the reference function

```
const onFlipBackCard = () => {
        isFlipped.value = false;
    }
```

I use normal `<script>` with above code and it work. I'm newbie in Vue 3, so I still want use `<script setup>` to get more knowledge. I hope I can get resolve code in `<script setup>`.

Normal `<script>` code:

- InteractScene.vue

```
<script>
import CardGame from "@/components/CardGame.vue";

export default {
    props: {
        cardContext: {
            type: Array,
            default: function () { return [] }
        }
    },
    components: {
        CardGame
    },
    data() {
        return {
            rules: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        checkRule(card){
            console.log(card)
            if(this.rules.length === 2) return false
            this.rules.push(card)

            if(this.rules.length === 2 && this.rules[0].value === this.rules[1].value){
                console.log("true...")
            } else if(this.rules.length === 2 && this.rules[0].value !== this.rules[1].value){
                console.log("Wrong...")
                this.$refs[`card-${this.rules[0].index}`][0].onFlipBackCard();
                this.$refs[`card-${this.rules[1].index}`][0].onFlipBackCard();

                this.rules = []
            } else return false
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

- CardGame.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            card: {
                type: [String, Number, Array, Object]
            },
            imgBackFaceUrl: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                isFlipped: false
            };
        },

        methods: {
            onToggleFlipCard() {
                this.isFlipped = !this.isFlipped;
                if(this.isFlipped) this.$emit("flip", this.card)
            },
            onFlipBackCard(){
                this.isFlipped = false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My source code: https://github.com/Jdsatashi/Vue-PokeGame

Answer (score 1):

`ref.value` is not the same as `this.$refs`. The relevant Vue 3 documentation that should hopefully clear this up is the page on [Template Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs).

You must declare your own custom `ref` array, which will hold the `:ref=` attributes of your DOM elements. The ref attribute should also be the exact same as your ref variable name.

```js
const cards = ref([])
```

```html
<CardGame v-for="(card, index) in cardContext"
  :ref="cards"
  ...
/>
```

`cards` is then a searchable, indexed array you can reference elsewhere in your code to find whatever element you need, when you need it.

```js
cards.value[0].onFlipBackCard();
```

---

As a side note, I'd recommend using a better `:key` than index, as it's not reliable for tracking changes to a list. It can be used ok in certain situations but if your app involves any kind of adding, removing or changing of your card list you'll want to use a different property for key such as some kind of unique id.

Comment: From your suggest I was making some change in my code. And it's still not work.
When I use `rules.value[0].onFlipBackCard();`, the `flipBackCard()` was got error Unresolved. I have to add
`defineExpose({
        flipBackCard
    })`
to CardGame.vue. Event so, the `rules.value[0].flipBackCard();` still get error.
The error I got from browser console:
`Uncaught TypeError: rule[0].flipBackCard is not a function
    at Proxy.checkRule (InteractScene.vue?t=1692529081212:66:17)
    at _createBlock.onFlip._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed>`